# Why is DoubleBuffer.put() allocating memory, and how should I avoid this happening?

Tags: java, android, memory, nio

In my Android app, I have a loop in a thread that does some processing of data stored in `DoubleBuffer` objects. To my surprise, [`put(DoubleBuffer)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/DoubleBuffer.html#put(java.nio.DoubleBuffer)) appears to be allocating memory!

Is this something I should have expected? To me, it seems to go against everything I thought I understood about NIO buffers. Is there something I should be doing to avoid it?

I'm able to reproduce this with a minimal example that simply copies between two buffers in a loop. Run via Android Studio on a physical phone running Android 4.4.2, the log is filled with lines like the following:

> ```
> D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2032K, 55% free 6556K/14500K, paused 11ms, total 11ms
> ```

If I comment out the call to `put()`, this does not happen.

Here's the code I reproduced this issue with, written on top of the "empty activity" template:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Thread thread;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                DoubleBuffer buffer1 = DoubleBuffer.allocate(5000);
                DoubleBuffer buffer2 = DoubleBuffer.allocate(buffer1.capacity());
                while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                    // set remaining to capacity so that entire buffer is copied
                    buffer1.clear();
                    buffer2.clear();
                    buffer2.put(buffer1);
                    Thread.yield();
                }
            }
        });
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        if (thread != null) {
            thread.interrupt();
            thread = null;
        }
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

And here's the relevant parts of `app/build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 25
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
}
```

Comment: Your code is pointless. Putting an empty buffer into another one transfers no data. Try something real.

Comment: @EJP `buffer.clear().remaining() == buffer.capacity()`, so it should transfer the entire buffer. I didn't generate fake test data because the test is of memory usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsing the AOSP source code, this appears to be exactly what's happening. The relevant code for `DoubleBuffer.put(DoubleBuffer)` in [4.4.2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/android-4.4.2_r2.0.1/luni/src/main/java/java/nio/DoubleBuffer.java#437) is:

```
double[] doubles = new double[src.remaining()];
src.get(doubles);
put(doubles);
```

So they're paying the cost of a heap allocation, so that they can reap the benefits of `System.arraycopy()`. This same code is used for a `DoubleBuffer` view of a `ByteBuffer`, whether direct or not.

From what I can tell, this was the code from at least as far back as 2.3. As of Android [7.0](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/android-7.0.0_r1/ojluni/src/main/java/java/nio/DoubleBuffer.java#396), this has been replaced with:

```
int n = src.remaining();
if (n > remaining())
    throw new BufferOverflowException();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    put(src.get());
```

So if you want to avoid allocating memory in a tight loop, across all Android versions, and you really want to (or must) use buffers, you need to implement the `put(DoubleBuffer)` functionality yourself. For example:

```
while (fromBuffer.hasRemaining()) {
    toBuffer.put(fromBuffer.get());
}
```

Or, if you're copying from an array-backed buffer (`!fromBuffer.isDirect()`):

```
toBuffer.put(fromBuffer.array(), fromBuffer.position(), fromBuffer.remaining());
```

---

The situation is the same for all the non-byte buffers (`IntBuffer`, `LongBuffer`, `ShortBuffer`, `FloatBuffer`, `CharBuffer`).